# Getting control back to unix shell script

Tags: python, unix

I am calling a python script from unix "Hello.sh"

```
echo "Executing python script"
java weblogic.WLST weblogic_generate.py $myh $myp
echo "Completed Execution"
```

But After executing the python script the control does not come back to unix and  echo "Completed Execution" is not printed. Can you suggest how can I get it to work ?

Comment: You have to make it wait so you can see the message before it disappears. Do you want it to expect a keypress or something?

Comment: Could you explain the role of the `java` command? It seems to be running the python script as part of its execution; perhaps the `java` command is never returning?

Comment: You tell us what **doesn't** happen after the `java` command runs. Please tell us what **does** happen. Does it return to the shell prompt? Does the line in the script that follows `echo` complete? Does a window disappear? Are you logged out of the your Gnome session?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
sleep 3
```

as the last line so it waits 3 seconds after displaying `Completed Execution`